# Can i replicate this in r (approach through Excel)

Tags: r

I have more or less redesigned every approach that i used in excel in R because my df has now millions of rows. Only this remaining step is left

```
AccountNo<-c(11223344,11223344,11223344,1133399,1133399,1133399,1133399,127788,127788)
TransDesc<-c("BUY","BUY","SELL","SELL","SELL","BUY","BUY","SELL","BUY")
Date<-c("2019-10-07","2019-10-08","2019-10-04","2020-01-13","2020-01-12","2020-01-15","2020-01-16","2020-02-08","2020-02-09")
```

I want to add two additional columns. The first column will subtract maximum BUY date from each SELL category and maximum SELL date from each BUY category and the second column will calculate minimum BUY date from each SELL category and minimum SELL date from each BUY category.

Expected output:

```
AccountNo<-c(11223344,11223344,11223344,1133399,1133399,1133399,1133399,127788,127788)
TransDesc<-c("BUY","BUY","SELL","SELL","SELL","BUY","BUY","SELL","BUY")
Date<-c("2019-10-07","2019-10-08","2019-10-04","2020-01-13","2020-01-12","2020-01-15","2020-01-16","2020-02-08","2020-02-09")
Max<-c("-3","-4","4","3","4","-2","-3","1","-1")
Min<-c("-3","-4","3","2","3","-3","-4","1","-1")
```

I replicated this in excel due to maxifs and minifs when there were only 100 rows but with million rows, its definitely not feasible.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you can search in stack step by step. This simple operations have been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'AccountNo', get the difference between the `max`, `min` 'Date' where the 'TransDesc' is either 'SELL' or 'BUY'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
    group_by(AccountNo) %>%
    mutate(Max = as.numeric(max(Date[TransDesc == 'SELL']) - 
                     max(Date[TransDesc == 'BUY'])),
           Min = as.numeric(min(Date[TransDesc == 'SELL'])- 
                     min(Date[TransDesc == 'BUY'])) )
```

Comment: Works thanks! Was kind of concerned with the signs because it will always be SELL - BUY for Max and MIN. I will base my answer around it

Comment: @FatimaS if you check my solution it is subsetting `SELL` find the max `-` subset of 'BUY'

Comment: Oh, i got it. Sorry. Took me a while to understand!